# How to increase accuracy of predictions by neural network made from scratch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm relatively new to machine learning, and as a starter project, I decided to implement my own neural network from scratch in Python using NumPy. As such, I have manually implemented methods for forward propagation, backpropagation, and calculating function derivatives.

For my testing data, I wrote a function that generates values of sin(x). When I finally create and train my network, my outputs fluctuate quite a lot with each trial and are significantly off the true values(although they are a decent improvement over the initial predictions).

I have tried adjusting quite a few settings, including the learning rate, number of neurons, number of layers, training iterations, and activation function, but I still end up with a squared cost of around 0.1 over my input data.

I think my derivative functions and chain rule expressions are correct since when I use just one input sample I get a near-perfect answer.

Adding more input data, however, significantly reduces the accuracy of the network.

Do you guys have any suggestions for how to improve this network, or is there anything I'm doing wrong currently?

My code:

```py
import numpy as np

#Generate input data for the network
def inputgen():
    inputs=[]
    outputs=[]
    i=0.01
    for x in range(10000):
        inputs.append([round(i,7)])
        outputs.append([np.sin(i)]) #output is sin(x)
        i+=0.0001
    return [inputs,outputs]

#set training input and output
inputs = np.array(inputgen()[0]) 
outputs = np.array(inputgen()[1])

#sigmoid activation function and derivative
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return sigmoid(x)*(1-sigmoid(x))

#tanh activation function and derivative
def tanh(x):
    return np.tanh(x)

def tanh_derivative(x):
    return 1-((tanh(x))**2)

#Layer class
class Layer:
    def __init__(self,num_neurons,num_inputs,inputs):
        self.num_neurons = num_neurons #number of neurons in hidden layers
        self.num_inputs = num_inputs #number of input neurons(1 in the case of testing data)
        self.inputs = inputs
        self.weights = np.random.rand(num_inputs,num_neurons)*np.sqrt(1/num_inputs) #weights initialized by Xavier function
        self.biases = np.zeros((1,num_neurons)) #biases initialized as 0
        self.z = np.dot(self.inputs,self.weights)+self.biases #Cacluate z
        self.a = tanh(self.z) #Calculate activation

        self.dcost_a = [] #derivative of cost with respect to activation
        self.da_z = [] #derivative of activation with respect to z
        self.dz_w = [] #derivative of z with respect to weight
        self.dcost_w = [] #derivative of cost with respect to weight

        self.dcost_b = [] #derivative of cost with respect to bias

    #functions used in forwardpropagation
    def compute_z(self):
        self.z = np.dot(self.inputs,self.weights)+self.biases
        return self.z
    def activation(self):
        self.a = tanh(self.compute_z())

    def forward(self):
        self.activation()

#Network class
class Network: 
    def __init__(self,num_layers,num_neurons,num_inputs,inputs,num_outputs,outputs):
        self.learningrate = 0.01 #learning rate
        self.num_layers=num_layers #number of hidden layers
        self.num_neurons=num_neurons #number of neurons in hidden layers
        self.num_inputs = num_inputs #number of input neurons
        self.inputs=inputs 
        self.expected_outputs=outputs 

        self.layers=[]
        for x in range(num_layers):
            if x==0:
                self.layers.append(Layer(num_neurons,num_inputs,inputs)) #Initial layer with given inputs
            else:
                #Other layers have an input which is the activation of previous layer
                self.layers.append(Layer(num_neurons,len(self.layers[x-1].a[0]),self.layers[x-1].a))

        self.prediction = Layer(num_outputs,num_neurons,self.layers[-1].a) #prediction
        self.layers.append(self.prediction)
        self.cost = (self.prediction.a-self.expected_outputs)**2 #cost

    #forwardpropagation
    def forwardprop(self):
        for x in range(self.num_layers+1):
            if(x!=0):
                self.layers[x].inputs=self.layers[x-1].a
            self.layers[x].forward()
        self.prediction=self.layers[-1]  #update prediction value

    def backprop(self):
        self.cost = (self.prediction.a-self.expected_outputs)**2
        for x in range(len(self.layers)-1,-1,-1):
            if(x==len(self.layers)-1):
                dcost_a = 2*(self.prediction.a-self.expected_outputs) #derivative of cost with respect to activation for output layer
            else:
                #derivative of cost with respect to activation for hidden layers(chain rule)
                dcost_a=np.zeros((len(self.layers[x].inputs),self.num_neurons)).T
                dcost_a1=self.layers[x+1].dcost_a.T
                da_z1=self.layers[x+1].da_z.T
                dz_a=(self.layers[x+1].weights).T

                for z in range(len(dcost_a1)):
                    dcost_a+=((dcost_a1[z])*da_z1)
                    for j in range(len(dcost_a)):
                        dcost_a[j]*=dz_a[z][j]
                dcost_a=dcost_a.T

            self.layers[x].dcost_a=dcost_a

            #derivative of activation with respect to z
            da_z = tanh_derivative(self.layers[x].z)
            self.layers[x].da_z=da_z

            #derivative of z with respect to weights
            dz_w = []
            if x!=0:
                dz_w=self.layers[x-1].a
            else:
                dz_w=self.inputs
            self.layers[x].dz_w=dz_w

        #change weights and biases
        for x in range(len(self.layers)-1,-1,-1):
            #Average each of the derivatives over all training samples
            self.layers[x].dcost_a=np.average(self.layers[x].dcost_a,axis=0)
            self.layers[x].da_z=np.average(self.layers[x].da_z,axis=0)
            self.layers[x].dz_w=(np.average(self.layers[x].dz_w,axis=0)).T

            self.layers[x].dcost_w = np.zeros((self.layers[x].weights.shape))
            self.layers[x].dcost_b = self.layers[x].dcost_a*self.layers[x].da_z

            for v in range(len(self.layers[x].dz_w)):
                self.layers[x].dcost_w[v] = (self.layers[x].dcost_a*self.layers[x].da_z)*self.layers[x].dz_w[v]

            #update weights and biases
            self.layers[x].weights-=(self.layers[x].dcost_w)*self.learningrate
            self.layers[x].biases-=(self.layers[x].dcost_b)*self.learningrate

    #train the network
    def train(self):
        for x in range(1000):
            self.backprop()
            self.forwardprop()


Network1 = Network(3,3,1,inputs,1,outputs)

Network1.train()
print(Network1.prediction.a)
```

Sample input:

```
[[0.01  ]
 [0.0101]
 [0.0102]
 ...
 [1.0097]
 [1.0098]
 [1.0099]]
```

Sample output:

```
[[0.37656753]
 [0.37658777]
 [0.37660802]
 ...
 [0.53088048]
 [0.53089046]
 [0.53090043]]
```

Expected output:

```
[[0.00999983]
 [0.01009983]
 [0.01019982]
 ...
 [0.84667225]
 [0.84672546]
 [0.84677865]]
```

Comment: its quite common to adjust the learning rate within the program as well, consider using a cross entropy function to do this

Comment: @JSwang Hey, thanks for your help. I did, however, adjust the learning rate quite a few times(from 0.01 up to 0.5), but I’m still getting pretty inaccurate results.

Comment: you did? not by hard coding it, by adding in a function to tweak the the learning rate as the program ran?

Comment: @JSwang Oh I see what you mean. Sorry, I misunderstood. I haven’t tried that. How exactly would that work?Would I just change the learning rate every iteration of training?

Answer (score 1):

I would keep track of the cost_history and update your learning rate as such.

If you have been 
- getting closer to the actual value, increase learning rate by 5%
- getting further away, decrease the learning rate by 50%

```
def update_learning_rate(self):
    if(len(self.cost_history) < 2):
        return

    if(self.cost_history[0] > self.cost_history[1]):
        self.learning_rate /= 2
    else:
        self.learning_rate *= 1.05
```

this should actually yield surprisingly better results

what usually happens is that you might be getting stuck in one of the local minima (d) and not the absolute minimum (b). Ignore the labels, this is just a random photo I found online.

[image: 1]

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! I’ll try this out.

Comment: np, let me know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

Few things I would recommend to try:

1. ReLu activation for hidden layers. Tanh may not work so well for
   multi-layered network.
2. If you are doing regression, try linear activation for output layer.
3. Experiment with different target functions. sin(x) may be crazy
   difficult for small neural network to understand. Try something simpler
   like polynomials and increase complexity gradually.